# iPhone MapKit, get location of the dropped pin

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

I'm creating an iPhone application that gets the user to drop a pin where ever they want. After they drop the pin the user then clicks on it and i want it to show the location of the pin in the call out as the subtitle.

I have the mapview set up as well as the call out working and also the user is able to drop the pin where ever they want to on the map.

I know there is a tutorial for dragging and dropping a pin and they do cover something of this sort. But i'm actually really confused and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I've a good tutorial regarding the draggable pin.

The source code is available: http://github.com/digdog/MapKitDragAndDrop